# Error limits when we have 4 lengths adding up and then finding its mean?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

I have the following readings for length of a wire:

10.2 ± 0.1 cm

10.3 ± 0.1 cm

10.1 ± 0.1 cm

10.2 ± 0.1 cm

Now, when I find out the mean value, I get:

(10.2 ± 0.1 + 10.3 ± 0.1 + 10.1 ± 0.1 + 10.2 ± 0.1) cm / 4

So, will I get the answer as (10.2 ± 0.1) cm or (10.2 ± 0.4) cm? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your textbook or lab manual will have what method they want you to use.
But without more information, I would personally report the [standard error of the mean,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_the_mean) which is neither of the two methods you've shown. This method takes into account the number of measurements; more measurements tends to result in a smaller reported error.